# Very basic question about multiplying by minus sign

Tags: differential-geometry

If we have $d(Y-U)=0$ where $Y$ and $U$ are any two constants, can we multiply this by $(-)$ to get $d(U-Y)=0$? I am worried that something could stop me from doing it because of the total differential.

Answer (score 1):

Differentials are linear, and $-1$ is a constant, so it's absolutely fine.